# Select one element in class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I made a table with a `for` Loop. Something like this (of course not exactly my code)

```
<table>
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <tr>
    <td><label class='shutDownText'> Shutdown Time </label></td>
    <td><input type='time' class='selectShutdown'/> <input type='button' value='Accept'/></td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.selectShutdown').change(function()
    {
        $('.shutDownText').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

You may already recognized my problem. Whenever I click on `.selectShutdown`, it changes the text of every Text in `.shutDownText`.
How can I only select the one element, that is in the same `<tr>` Tag.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
$('.selectShutdown').change(function()
    {
        $(this).closest("tr").find('.shutDownText').text($(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use closest function of jquery which select only the closest element like this

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.selectShutdown').change(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('.shutDownText').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```